# Qt auto generated form provides wrong path to source code files

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, qtgui, qcustomplot

I have added qcustomplot.h/.c files to my Qt project. They are located in: "QT_PROJECT_DIR/QCustomPlot/".

Every time I use the designer in Qt Creator and build I get this error in ui_mainwindow.h:

```
error: ../../qcustomplot.h: No such file or directory
#include "../../qcustomplot.h"
```

This is of course true as it is located in: "QT_PROJECT_DIR/QCustomPlot/"

How do I change how Qt Designer auto generate this path?

If it helps, here is my .pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-01-12T00:44:44
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets widgets opengl printsupport

TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    QCustomPlot/qcustomplot.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    QCustomPlot/qcustomplot.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY =
```

Comment: Please paste more of the error message. Which file is trying to include qcustomplot.h?

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow without enough 'reputation' somehow that i can not add a comment to @Shea Belsky. i followed the instruction of his and solve the problem. i think he may forgot one step in his answer. Here is my step by step according to his: Step 1: Open the ***.ui file which contains the qcustomplot item. Step 2: Right click the qcustomplot item AND CLICK 'PROMOTED WIDGETS' ! Step 3: Double click the path of QCustomPlot, then change it to QCustomPlot/qcustomplot.cpp from ../../customplot. just like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY9Am.png) Finally, t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your include seems to be wrong:

```
#include "../../qcustomplot.h"
```

Since you do not add the QCustomPlot folder to your `INCLUDEPATH`, you would need to include the file as follows:

```
#include "QCustomPlot/qcustomplot.h"
```

Alternatively, you could change the `INCLUDEPATH` as follows:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$QT_PROJECT_DIR/QCustomPlot/
```

and then you could include the header without the ugly `../../` relative reference as follows:

```
#include "qcustomplot.h"
```

It is a rule of thumb to avoid such relative include paths in the source and headers files themselves because the structure can change at any time, or may be different on a different machine, et al. It is better resolved by the buildsystem and include paths.

Comment: I had to include the path as the auto-generated file always created the path I showed in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and have solved it.

It was caused by the path of qcustomplot object in `xxx.ui`.

Step 1: Open the `***.ui` file which contains the qcustomplot item.

Step 2: Right click the qcustomplot item

Step 3: Double click the path of QCustomPlot, then change it to `QCustomPlot/qcustomplot.cpp` from `../../customplot`.

Finally, the header of `ui_***.h` can auto include `QCustomPlot/qcustomplot.cpp`, instead of `../../qcustomplot.h`.

My native language isn't English. If you find grammar mistake in my reply, please inform me. Let me correct it.